# biased random guess classification

Tags: r, classification

I try to get used to some classification methods in R (kNN, Decision Trees, SVM) and I am just wondering:
Is there a way to do a biased random guess classification to see the real performance of the classificator?

Update:
Example: There are two classes, but its a imbalanced data set. Class 1 makes 70 %, class 2 30 %. Therefore, its not a big deal do "guess" 70 % correct by classifying each data record as class 1.
So I want to show the following:
Classificator: 90 % identified as TP
random guess (biased, for the known distribution): 73 %

The random guess should just identify the data records by guessing. If the distribution would be balanced, it would show approx. a 50/50 result. With the known distribution it would show a approx. 70/30 result.
Hopefully this clarifies the question a little bit...

Thanks!

Comment: When you post a general question with no code, people are going to see it as a statistical question rather than one that asks for a specific coding solution.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for - but you can imagine a chimp who is going to be replaced by your code; how many classes do you have in your case ?!

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I added a update, hopefully its better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Matlab you'd do this for a single observation (assuming a binary classification):

```
p = 0.7;
y = rand() > p;
```

or if your input set of binary labels is a vector `Y` then you can do:

```
p = mean(Y);
y = rand(size(Y)) <= p;
```

I imagine the R code would be nearly identical.